# MySQL cannot create a user that will allow remote connection

Tags: mysql

MySQL 5.7 will not allow me to connect:

```
CREATE DATABASE testtable DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8;
CREATE USER 'test'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'testpass';
GRANT ALL ON testtable.* TO 'test'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'testpass';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;

mysql -h xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx -u test -ptestpass
mysql: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'test'@'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx' (using password: YES)
```

On the mysql server I have

```
 bind-address = 0.0.0.0
```

Also my ip address is allowed to the firewall.

But as my user root username and password I can connect.  Also on the server itself I can connect with test/testpass.  Just not remote.

What is wrong with how I created the user?

```
select user,host from mysql.user;
+----------------+-----------+
| user           | host      |
+----------------+-----------+
| test          | %         |
```

Comment: Try checking results of `SHOW CREATE USER 'test'@'%'` and also `SHOW GRANTS FOR 'test'@'%'` to make sure they're as expected.

Comment: I had better results just skipping any bind-address entry. Just make sure your user is `@'%'` and you removed `skip-networking` from my.cnf.

Answer (score 0):

```
mysql -h xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx -u test -ptestpass

Access denied for user 'druid'@'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx'
```

Different users. Do you see? Try to remove space between `test`, I mean:

```
mysql -h xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx -utest -ptestpass
```

Comment: `-u` works with a space for me all the time, why wouldn't it work for him?

Comment: @Tampa: It looks like you have two users. Could you please provide result of this query: `select user,host from mysql.user; `(only related info for this user)

Comment: You should send that comment to the OP, not me.

Comment: @pivanchy I added the info you requested

Comment: @Tampa: try to replace your part: `GRANT ALL ON testtable.* TO 'test'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'testpass';` with this one: `GRANT ALL ON testtable.* to test@'ipaddress' IDENTIFIED BY 'testpass';`

Comment: @pivanchy no, that is simply not supposed to work like this. The % is a placeholder for all possible ips...

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the password using the PASSWORD function in MySQL.

```
set password for 'test'@'%' = PASSWORD('testpass');
```